# Handle touch events for each touch point (FMX Android)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

We currently have the Location property for each touch point.

The event procedure is:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormTouch(Sender: TObject; const Touches: TTouches;
  const Action: TTouchAction);
```

Action is not associated with each touch, only detects if touched or not.

If we want to have total control of every touch point, we need another property as TTouchAction.

Something like:

```pascal
TTouch = record
  Location: TPointF;
  Action: TTouchAction;
end;
```

Original declaration (FMX.Types) is:

```pascal
TTouch = record
  Location: TPointF;
end;
```

Does anyone know any workaround?

I work with Delphi XE7.

UPDATE: Fixed!!

Add fmx.platform.android to "Uses".

I made the following changes to fmx.platform.android:

```pascal
var
  ACTION_Touches: array of Integer;

//Function Modded
function TPlatformAndroid.HandleAndroidMotionEvent(AEvent: PAInputEvent): Int32;
var
  I: Integer;
  MotionEvent: TMotionEvent;
begin
  Result := 0;

  FMotionEvents.Clear;

  SetLength(ACTION_touches, 1);

  for I := 0 to AMotionEvent_getPointerCount(AEvent) - 1 do
  begin
    MotionEvent.EventAction := AKeyEvent_getAction(AEvent) and AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_MASK;
    MotionEvent.Position := TWindowManager.Current.PixelToPoint(TPointF.Create(AMotionEvent_getX(AEvent, I),
      AMotionEvent_getY(AEvent, I)));
    MotionEvent.Shift :=[ssLeft];
    if AInputEvent_getType(AEvent) <> AINPUT_SOURCE_MOUSE then
      Include(MotionEvent.Shift, ssTouch);
    FMotionEvents.Add(MotionEvent);
    ACTION_touches[0] := (AKeyEvent_getAction(AEvent) and AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_PointerIndex_MASK) shr AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_PointerIndex_SHIFT;
  end;

  HandleMultiTouch;

  if (FActiveInteractiveGestures = []) or (FActiveInteractiveGestures = [TInteractiveGesture.Pan]) then
    ProcessAndroidMouseEvents;
  ProcessAndroidGestureEvents;
end;
```

Comment: What exactly are trying to do?

Comment: As far as I remember there's already an event that triggers and has information about all touch points, just check official documentation.

Comment: @SilverWarior It's for a game.

The form has two rectangles within each rectangle there is a label with a number.

If we touch any rectangle, the rectangle label changes to another number. I do this using "if Action = TTouchAction.Down then".

The problem is that if there is already a finger into a rectangle and touch the other rectangle, change the number of the two labels instead of changing only was pressed at the time.

Update with some more info above.

Comment: @PeterV. I have found no information in the documentation, only a report of something similar but not quite understand what it is: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx/qcmain.aspx?d=129217

Comment: @PeterV. OnTouch event does return multiple touch points (Touches is an arra of TTouch), but it doesen't exactly tell you when specific touch points has been touched, released or moved. You have to fogure out that by yourself. There is a whole article explaning on how to do that here: http://otapi.com/2014/10/07/working-with-multi-touch-input-in-delphi-xe7-part-1/

Comment: I found the solution, I do not know if it is well done, but it WORKS. Read up the solution.